# value not getting retrieved from request object

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to learn JSP and Servlets. While trying to retrieve the request object data in the jsp page that was sent from the servlet, I am getting blank browser page.

The issue will be resolved if I use the reference value(STUDENT_LIST) directly in the foreach loop. But if i use request.getParameterValues method as shown below in the code, then the value will not be retrieved.

StudentListServlet.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String [] studentList= {"vivek","mahesh","somesh","shivani"};
    request.setAttribute("STUDENTS_LIST", studentList);

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/student-list.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

}
```

Students-list.jsp

```
    <body>
        <%
            String[] StudentsList = request.getParameterValues("STUDENT_LIST");
        %>
        <c:forEach var="tempStudent" items="${StudentsList}">
    ${tempStudent}
    </c:forEach>
    </body>
```

I was expecting the output to be vivek mahesh ashish shivani but i am getting the blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters and attributes are completely different things. You're setting an *attribute*, and you expect to find it in the *parameter* values. That won't happen.

Also, stop using scriptlets in JSPs.

And don't expect JSP EL variables such as `${StudentsList}` to reference a scriptlet variable. It references an *attribute* named `StudentsList` (which doesn't exist). Not a scriptlet variable.

Your attribute is named `STUDENTS_LIST`, so it should be `${STUDENTS_LIST}`. And the scriptlet is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thankyou so much Nizet, I just got it now after reading your answer